# How to get images to chase my character in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I would like to create a simple game were you move a base image and a bunch of zombie images spawn and chase you. The other answers for this dident seem to help. Can someone give me something easy to understand that will help me acheieve this

Here is my code. Though the indentation is off, I can never copy it right:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((894, 894))
pygame.display.set_caption('Zombie Survival')
grumpy = pygame.image.load('grumpy.jpg')
grumpy_x = 800
grumpy_y = 100
grumpy = pygame.transform.scale(grumpy, (50, 50))
background  = pygame.image.load('grass.jpg').convert()
while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            grumpy_x = grumpy_x + 20
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                            grumpy_x = grumpy_x - 20
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                            grumpy_y = grumpy_y - 20
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                            grumpy_y = grumpy_y + 20
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(grumpy, (grumpy_x, grumpy_y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets break it down a bit:

> a bunch of zombie images spawn

We need a list of zombies coordinates then, so we know where to draw the zombies.

```
zombies = []
```

Then we make the zombies have an initial position somewhere random.

```
for _ in range(10):
    new_zombie = (random.randrange(SCREENX), random.randrange(SCREENY))
    zombies.append(new_zombie)
```

We want to be able to draw the zombies as well.

```
for zombie in zombies:
    screen.blit(zombieimg, zombie)
```

---

Now lets look at the other part, *updating* the zombie positions.

To move our zombies, we want to shift them by some amount in the direction of the player.

```
ZOMBIE_SPEED = 3

def update(zombie):
    x, y = zombie
    if grumpy_x > x:
        x += ZOMBIE_SPEED
    else:
        x -= ZOMBIE_SPEED
    if grumpy_y > y:
        y += ZOMBIE_SPEED
    else:
        y -= ZOMBIE_SPEED
    return x, y

zombies = [update(zombie) for zombie in zombies]
```

In other words, at each time step, we want to move each zombie towards a player by some amount.

---

Warning: This is probably the easiest way to do it, because it glosses over some of the complexity you will face later on. You should learn about [objects and classes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) and how to use them in the context of [pygame sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html) before you get overwhelmed.

Keeping track of zombies and players and bullets and everything else individually will be painful, and it is much easier to just track sprites once your game gets complex enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should start thinking the game before going around a code it, what you have doesn't look good to me, any modularity for the game just will cause your work to be harder...
Try creating a class for the zombie, and make and update() function with the behaviour you want them to do (in this case seeking for the main character), they should have an image and x and y position as well as your player; transform that x and y coordinates so the zoombie get closer to the current position of the player.

```
class Zombie:
    def __init__(self, initX, initY, image = "default.png"):
        self.x = initX
        self.y = initY
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)

    def update(self, playerX, playerY):
         ##stuff to get to player and update the zombie position
```

generate the zombies:
    zombiLst = []
    for i in range(10):
        zombiLst.append(Zombie(100,100, "zombie.png"))

Then in your loop:

```
while True:
    ##your stuff here
    ##update the zombies
    for i in zombiLst.length():
        zombiLst[i].update()
```

something like this should do.